# Django and static website

Tags: javascript, css, django, html, angularjs

Hey I am pretty new to Django framework.
I chose Django as my back-end framework and angular.js as my front-end framework.
and I have already build my own site(static files only:css.html,javascript)
and I have a couple of major questions:

1. In the routing management of my urls, can I only redirect to index.html and from there all the routing will be handle automatically in client side.which means I need only need to write a python code in django views? if so what is the code?
   is it something like that:

   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),)
2. Does angular.js  framework have issues with django framework,which I need to know about? 
   for example I saw that django templates use curly brackets in html code ,which also used by angular.js.

Comment: I did it: I reworded 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular and Django can play very nicely.

Typically you have one url (your main page) where your angular app lives. From that point the rest of your routing would be handled by Angular if you choose.

To load data for your app, you may want to make ajax requests to an `/ajax/` endpoint, for which you'll want to write Django views that return `json`.

Specifically to address 2: if you use Angular variables in your template (ie: `{{ myvar }}`) you will need to wrap them in `{% verbatim %}` or Django will attempt to render them when the page loads intially, for example:

```
{% verbatim %}
    <!-- django does not try to render this now -->
    <div>{{ angular_var }}</div>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Hope that helps,
Aaron

Comment: ok, and if I wrap them in {% verbatim %}  will angular.js will recognize them? I am pretty new to angular.js(also) and I know that only {{ }} works...

Comment: Yes, if you don't use `{% verbatim %}`, django will try to render the variables in and fail silently since they won't be in your context. Using `{% verbatim %}` will tell django to leave the `{{}}` curly braces alone so angular can use them.

Comment: ok, I read your answer second time and now I got your point :) thx you solve me,my second question.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, you can and you did it. From your code, Django only handle the "/" url. Besides make sure you have router code in front-end.
2. If you don't use the Django templates, all will be OK. If you use the Django templates and AngularJS at same file, that will cause conflict easily( Django template and AngularJS use "{{}}" syntax both ). Maybe you can read this project: [django-angular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular)

Comment: one last question: 
what do you mean when you said router code in client-end code?

I have a link in my index.html to another main.html and from there I handle my urls as ngviews using angular.js

Comment: @Brk what i said just mean you have to maintain your router table in front-end. That can be thought as using ngRouter for you case